# MSMQ and SSIS - Read messages & Write them to SQL table

Tags: sql-server, ssis, msmq, sql-server-2016

Basically I want to read messages from MSMQ public queue and push them in to SQL Server table every 2 hours.
So a separate application writes the messages to MSMQ server in this format, see below sample message (contains 2 fields):

```
 <?xml version="1.0"?>
 <Person>
      <FirstName>John</FirstName>
      <LastName>Smith</LastName>
 </Person>
```

Ideally I imagine an SSIS package (that a SQL agent job can execute every couple of hours) that read the messages and populate a SQL table.
I came across SSIS package "Message Queue Task" > Receive but don't know how to read such object and then push it further to a SQL table.

SQL table would be something like

```
 dbo.Person (FirstName VARCHAR(50)
           , LastName VARCHAR(50))
```

I'm using SQL Server 2016.

Could you please advise/walk me through here how efficiently I can achieve this? 
Your sugesstions are greatly appreciated

Comment: https://www.google.co.uk/search?q=consuming+msmq+from+ssis

Comment: Tom. You should post that as an answer.

Comment: Actually, based on my research so far, I don't think this is possible to read MSMQ object from SSIS package. I ended up creating C# console application to achieve this. Thanks though.